# Node.js module.exports vs filesystem

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node when I require a file, it's normally and by default an object coming from node's module exports.

So I am wondering **other than the synchronously nature of `module.exports` and the asynchronously nature of `fs`** what would be the other differences between retrieving a JSON file via module.exports vs the filesystem library, good/bad | pros/cons. Thanks!

### scenario 1

**file_1.js**

`module.exports = [{A-JSON}];`

**file_2.js**

```
require json from ('./file_1');
console.log(json);
```

### scenario 2

**file_1.js**

`[{A-JSON}]`

**file_2.js**

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./file_1', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should know that `require` can also be used to load json files - as documented [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_require).

So for your second scenario, just rename to `file_1.json` and you can use require as well.

In that case, if you use `fs` you will need to `JSON.parse` your file manually, while `require` will automatically do it for you.

Another difference is that the `require` system uses a cache, so that if you want to use the same object in another file, it will not read again from the filesystem

I think it's better to follow the standard and use `require` whenever it's possible.